# При клике на разные кнопки всегда открывается последний блок?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста почему при клике на .catalog__title открывается всегда последний блок .catalog__items, а не у каждого свой? Спасибо

```js
function catalog() {

  const catalogTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__title');
  const catalogArrows = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__item-arrow');
  const catalogItems = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__items');

  if (catalogTitles) {

    catalogTitles.forEach(title => {
      title.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        catalogItems.forEach(item => {
          catalogItems.forEach(el => { el.classList.remove('_catalog-open'); });
          item.classList.add('_catalog-open')
        });
      })
    });

    catalogArrows.forEach(arrow => {
      arrow.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        catalogItems.forEach(el => { el.classList.remove('_catalog-open'); });
      });
    });
  }
}
catalog()
```

```css
.catalog__title {
  padding: 15px 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.catalog__items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -110%;
  padding: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease 0s;
  overflow: auto;
  background: grey;
}

.catalog__items._catalog-open {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="catalog__column">
    <div class="catalog__content">
      <div class="catalog__link">
        <div class="catalog__title">
          Клик
        </div>
        <div class="catalog__items">
          <div class="catalog__item-arrow">Клик назад</div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст2</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="catalog__column">
    <div class="catalog__content">
      <div class="catalog__link">
        <div class="catalog__title">
          Клик
        </div>
        <div class="catalog__items">
          <div class="catalog__item-arrow">Клик назад</div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст4</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст5</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст6</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="catalog__column">
    <div class="catalog__content">
      <div class="catalog__link">
        <div class="catalog__title">
          Клик
        </div>
        <div class="catalog__items">
          <div class="catalog__item-arrow">Клик назад</div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст7</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст8</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст9</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому вы в коде открываете все блоки по-очереди, закрывая остальные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нет необходимости внутри цикла делать еще один цикл с catalogItems. В этом и кроется проблема, у Вас всегда при клике перебирается вся коллекция catalogItems и в конечном счете добавляется класс последнему элементу.
Просто обращайтесь к следующему элементу через `nextElementSibling` и добавляйте нужный класс.

```
 catalogTitles.forEach(title => {
      title.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        title.nextElementSibling.classList.add('_catalog-open');
      })
    });
```

```js
function catalog() {

  const catalogTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__title');
  const catalogArrows = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__item-arrow');
  const catalogItems = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__items');

  if (catalogTitles) {

    catalogTitles.forEach(title => {
      title.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        title.nextElementSibling.classList.add('_catalog-open');
      })
    });

    catalogArrows.forEach(arrow => {
      arrow.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        catalogItems.forEach(el => { el.classList.remove('_catalog-open'); });
      });
    });
  }
}
catalog()
```

```css
.catalog__title {
  padding: 15px 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.catalog__items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -110%;
  padding: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease 0s;
  overflow: auto;
  background: grey;
}

.catalog__items._catalog-open {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="catalog__column">
    <div class="catalog__content">
      <div class="catalog__link">
        <div class="catalog__title">
          Клик
        </div>
        <div class="catalog__items">
          <div class="catalog__item-arrow">Клик назад</div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст2</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="catalog__column">
    <div class="catalog__content">
      <div class="catalog__link">
        <div class="catalog__title">
          Клик
        </div>
        <div class="catalog__items">
          <div class="catalog__item-arrow">Клик назад</div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст4</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст5</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст6</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="catalog__column">
    <div class="catalog__content">
      <div class="catalog__link">
        <div class="catalog__title">
          Клик
        </div>
        <div class="catalog__items">
          <div class="catalog__item-arrow">Клик назад</div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст7</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст8</a>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__item">
            <a href="#" class="catalog__subsubtitle">Текст9</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```